# Close all open dialogs

Tags: sapui5

If I open two dialogs

```js
dialogBusy = new sap.m.BusyDialog();
dialogBusy.setShowCancelButton(true);
dialogBusy.setTitle("1");
dialogBusy.open();

dialogBusy = new sap.m.BusyDialog();
dialogBusy.setShowCancelButton(true);
dialogBusy.setTitle("2");
dialogBusy.open();          
dialogBusy.close();         
//dialogBusy.close();
```

When I call close function, I close only the 2nd dialog (correct).
How can I close all dialogs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two different dialog instances.

```html
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons"></script>
<script>
    var dialogBusy = new sap.m.BusyDialog();
    dialogBusy.setShowCancelButton(true);
    dialogBusy.setTitle("1");
    dialogBusy.open();

    var dialogBusy2 = new sap.m.BusyDialog();
    dialogBusy2.setShowCancelButton(true);
    dialogBusy2.setTitle("2");
    dialogBusy2.open();
    setTimeout(function() {
        dialogBusy.close();
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        dialogBusy2.close();
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dialogs can be closed conveniently with [`sap/m/InstanceManager.closeAllDialogs`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.InstanceManager#methods/sap.m.InstanceManager.closeAllDialogs).

```js
// InstanceManager required from "sap/m/InstanceManager"
InstanceManager.closeAllDialogs(/*fnAfterClose?*/));
```